# Why the face broken in material preview/render in eevee?

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, eevee-render-engine

I just want to view the render in Eevee and I notice that when I preview in solid mode the facial model is no problem, but it seems broke in material preview and Eevee render. So could anyone tell me:

1. How to fix it?
2. Or because the original model is broken, then how can I make Eevee render in solid mode to show the light and background?

[image: solid]

[image: material]

[image: render]

I did not see the red dots here
[image]

Comment: This looks kind of like flipped normals to me. Check your face orientation and make sure everything is good.

Comment: sorry, I do really not know too much about blender, could u tell me how to adjust the orientation?

Comment: Click on the [viewport overlays button](https://i.imgur.com/KQI8LJB.png) and then select "Face Orientation". Once you do that, tell me whether you see any red spots in your mesh.

Comment: Hi I tried it @Cultmethod

Comment: Would you mind uploading your .blend file to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so I can take a closer look at what the problem is?

Comment: Ok, so, I rarely say this - but I have absolutely no idea what's going on with your scene. Blender keeps randomly crashing when I open it, there are eyeballs floating in random places, and there is no organization to your file. How did you create this? Did you import this model from another 3D package?

Comment: right actually that is not made by me so I remove some elements, as I say I really don't know Blender and just want to see the render result. So maybe I need to ask for an allowance from the author and upload the complete one later.

Answer (score 1):

After months of being stressed on this very issue myself... This is what the issue is... Remember in Blender it's always two things... Something simple and something silly...

It's your camera "AND ONLY" your camera... If you switch to cycles and everything works... it's your camera
[image]
Click on the camera icon on the properties tab...
Under "Lens" your "CLIP START" is too low... raise it just a little...
ex... if it's 0.1mm change it to 3mm
[image]
The same goes for your default/worldview...
It's the craziest thing...